# About RAM and STACK

Tags: stack, ram

Suppose we have opened an app in our mobile. As per my knowledge any app we opened comes to RAM.
1)Will it store in STACK?

2. What decides how much memory it takes from RAM?
3. Was the size of app( I mean we see size of app from play store while downloading Eg:13MB) and size it takes in RAM are same?If not what are these 2 sizes?

Answer (score 0):

1. Stack is a name given to a portion of memory. When you run a program, each program gets its own virtual address space, I say virtual because other programs can have the same address too! But the operating system takes care of mapping the virtual addresses of different process to the real address in the RAM. Now, Stack is the space in the virtual address where local variables, are stored. It grows down from high value address space to low value. I’ve simplified this greatly.

Virtual addressing is used to maintain a level of abstraction, the program should not get free access to the real memory, the OS should be able to control it and keep it secure.

2. it depends on the processes of the program, the code it runs. The variables it creates, the functions it calls. Depending on that it will request for those many pages,

(memory addressing is handled through pages, or sections of memory, and a page will usually contain a power of 2 bytes. So virtual page 1 can have address from 0 to 1023, virtual page 2 can go from 1024 to 2047, and this virtual page 2 can get mapped to real page 3 which has address from  2048 to 3071). You can read more on this.

and the OS will grant the request. It will dynamically change as well.

3. the size of the app is the filesize, or the size of the contents. This is stored in the disk/storage. It’s static, it will be the same, typically consisting of game files, images, etc.
   when running the program we don’t load all of that, just what we need. Execution of program, the memory it needs is different from the size of the code/ filesize.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stack is used to run some commands of the application such as nested module calls and computing arithmetic formulas.
2. Specific algorithms and computations used, app graphics, input & output size, ... impact memory usage.
3. No, the first is the installation package size of the app and the second is RAM size needed to run it and may vary during execution.